# Incrementing dates in a loop

Tags: c++, loops

This is an exercise; I'm forbidden to use built-in date function of C++ or any readily available library.

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


bool IsLeap(unsigned int  year)
{
    if (year % 4 != 0) return false;
    else
        if (year % 100 != 0) return true;
        else
            if (year % 400 != 0) return false;
            else
                return true;
}

class Date
{
public:
    unsigned short int Day;
    unsigned short int Month;
    unsigned short int Year;
    unsigned short int DayOfWeek;
};

int MonthLimit(int Month, int year)
{
    switch (Month)
    {
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
    {
        return 30;
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 12:
    {
        return 31;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
        if (IsLeap(year))
        {
            return 29;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            return 28;
            break;
        }

    }
}



const Date FirstDayEver = { 1, 1, 1900, 1 };  //January 1, 1900 was on a Monday.

int main()
{
    unsigned int years;
    cin >> years;

    vector<int> counters(7);   //whenever a 13th falls on a day X, we increment the Xth counter. It's that simple


    for (Date i = FirstDayEver; !((i.Day == 31) && (i.Month == 12) && (i.Year == 1900 + years - 1)); i.Day++)
    {
        i.DayOfWeek = (i.DayOfWeek + 1) % 7;
        if (i.Month == MonthLimit(i.Month, i.Year))
        {
            i.Month++;
            i.Day = 1;
            cout << "Proceeded to " << i.Day << "." << i.Month << "." << i.Year << "\n";
        }
        if ((i.Day == 31) && (i.Month == 12))
        {
            i.Year++;
            i.Day = 1;
            i.Month = 1;
            cout << "Proceeded to " << i.Day << "." << i.Month << "." << i.Year << "\n";
        }

        if (i.Day == 13)
        {
            counters[i.DayOfWeek]++;
            cout << i.Day << "." << i.Month << "." << i.Year << " was a " << i.DayOfWeek << "\n";
        }
    }

    cout << counters[6] << " " << counters[7] << " " << counters[1] << " " << counters[2] << " " << counters[3] << " " << counters[4] << " " << counters[5] << "\n";

    exit(0);
}
```

The debug info (`cout`s) is there to see whether anything happens in the loop. 
So far the only thing that happens is a lot of lines saying "13.1.1900 was a " varying number.
I think the desired logic of incrementing a date is rather clear from the code, but I'm trying to increment something wrong.
Where's my mistake?

Comment: As an aside why `exit(0);` instead of (the implicit) `return 0;` at the end of `main`?

Comment: That's what I'm asked to do. It has something to do with my code being submitted to a Linux machine which probably has trouble with simple `return 0;`.

Comment: No, Linux is certainly fine with more idiomatic code. Take a look at the second `if`-statement in the loop. That's ... so wrong (logic). Also, consider putting your date-normalization-code into a member-function `normalize()`.

Comment: Why? We've reached the end of a year and increment the year, starting with the first day of the next year.

Comment: Really? Let's see, you incremented to 31st december in the loop-head. The first if-statement makes that 1st of month 13. What does the second if-statement do then?

Comment: There isn't even supposed to be a month 13 :-) You're saying that I've written something wrong, but I can't see it; I'm thinking about how it's meant to work.

Comment: The computer assuredly has no problem with `return 0`. The `exit(0)` is simply bad and wrong. Being "asked" to do it is badder and wronger.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Looks okay to me?

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
if (i.Month == MonthLimit(i.Month, i.Year))
```

is comparing the month with the number of days in the month.
Since the first month is 1, and that month has 31 days, you will never increment the month.
Since you never increment the month, you will never increment the year.
(You would probably have spotted this easier if you had named the function "DaysInMonth", or something else that makes it clearer what it returns.)

You want

```
if (i.Day == MonthLimit(i.Month, i.Year))
```

Second, `MonthLimit` is missing a case for October.

Comment: Yes, the first part is true, and was an obvious mistake on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're complicating your increment procedure too much.
I'm actually still trying to work out exactly how it all fits together (edge cases etc) but it seems that you tried to do each day/month/year independantly.

You can do all your incrementing in a simple function like this:

```
void increment_Date(Date &d)
{
    d.DayOfWeek = (d.DayOfWeek + 1) % 7; //increase weekday
    if (++d.Day > MonthLimit(d.Month, d.Year)//increase day, if larger than month size...
    {
        d.Day = 1;                           //reset day to 1
        if (++d.Month > 12)                  //increase month, if larger than year size
        {
          d.Month = 1;                       //reset month to 1
          d.Year++;                          //increase year
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is simpler because I approached it in a slightly different way than you seem to have done.
In the function above, I increase the smallest unit first (day), check for overflow and then move up to month if needed (and so on).

This works in the same way that a car's mileage dial's digits only tick up when the dial reaches `10` and goes back to 0.  Or, adding 1 to 9 and 'overflowing' into the 10's digit of a number.

Otherwise your code is good.  The Switch statement for `MonthLimit` was a good choice.
I'd add a switch statement in a function to return a string for day of week:

```
std::String printable_DOW(int DOW)
{
    switch (DOW)
    case 0:
        return "Sunday";
    case 1:
        return "Monday";
    case 2:
        return "Tuesday";
    case 3:
        return "Wednesday";
    case 4:
        return "Thursday";
    case 5:
        return "Friday";
    case 6:
        return "Saturday";
}
```

and a `print_date` function too:

```
void print_date(Date d)
{
    std::cout<< printable_DOW(d.DayOfWeek) 
             << ", " << d.Day << "." << d.Month << "." d.Year;
}
```

and it's pretty easy to put it all together and use too:

```
int main
{

    Date my_date;
    my_date.Day = 1;
    my_date.Month = 1;
    my_date.Year = 2000;
    my_date.DayOfWeek = 0;  //assuming 0 == Sunday, 1 = Monday...
    for (int daycount = 0; daycount < 5114 /*days since 1/1/2000 to today*/; daycount++)
    {
        increment_date(my_date);
        //debug:
        print_date(my_date);
    }
    //print "today's" date:
    print_date(my_date);
}
```

As a class:
*It's mostly here and (mostly) works. Feel free to edit people!*

```
class date
{
private:
    unsigned short int day;
    unsigned short int month;
    unsigned short int year;
    unsigned short int day_of_week;
    int month_limit();
    bool is_leap_year();
public:
    date();
    date(int in_day, int in_month, int in_year, int in_day_of_week);
    date& date::operator=(date rhs)
    date& operator++();    //pre-increment (++date)
    date operator++(int);  //post-increment (date++)

    //these are "special" they don't work exactly as you might think and are slightly broken right now,
    //but I'm putting them in regardless
    //they also don't work on DOW right now.
    date& operator+=(const date& rhs)               
    date& operator-=(const date& rhs)
    inline date operator+(date lhs, const date& rhs)
    inline date operator-(date lhs, const date& rhs)
}
//phwew

date::date(int in_day, int in_month, int in_year, int in_day_of_week)
{
    this->day = in_day;
    this->month = in_month;
    this->year = in_year;
    this->day_of_week = in_doay_of_week;
}

date::month_limit()
{
    switch (this->month)
    {
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
    {
        return 30;
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 12:
    {
        return 31;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
        if (is_leap_year(this->year))
        {
            return 29;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            return 28;
            break;
        }

    }
}

bool is_leap_year()
{
    if (this->year % 4 != 0) return false;
    else
        if (this->year % 100 != 0) return true;
        else
            if (this->year % 400 != 0) return false;
            else
                return true;
}

date& date::operator=(date rhs)
{
  swap(rhs);
  return *this;
}

date& date::operator++()
{
    this->day_of_week = (this->day_of_week + 1) % 7; //increase weekday
    this->day++;
    if (++(this->day) > month_limit())           //increase day, if larger than month size...
        {
            this->day = 1;                           //reset day to 1
            if (++this->month > 12)                  //increase month, if larger than year size
            {
              this->month = 1;                       //reset month to 1
              this->year++;                          //increase year
            }
        }
    return *this;
}

date date::operator++(int)
{
    date tmp(*this);
    operator++();
    return tmp;
}

//adds years on, then months, then days
date& date::operator+=(const date& rhs)
{
    this->year  += rhs.year;
    this->month += rhs.month;
    this->day   += rhs.day;
    if (this->month > 12)  //get to the right month
    {
        this->year  = this->month / 12;
        this->month = this->month % 12;
    }
    if (this->day > month_limit())
    {
        this->month = this->day / month_limit();
        this->day   = this->day % month_limit();
        if (this->month > 12)  //recalculate  **yes, I know this is currently wrong if more than one month is added on in days**
        {
            this->year  = this->month / 12;
            this->month = this->month % 12;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

inline date date::operator+(date lhs, const date& rhs)
{
  lhs += rhs;
  return lhs;
}

//subtracts years, then months, then days
date& date::operator-=(const date& rhs)
{
    if ((rhs.year < this->year) || ((rhs.year == this->year) && (rhs.month < this->month))
       || (((rhs.year == this->year) && (rhs.month == this->month)) && (rhs.day < this->day)
    {
        swap(rhs);
    }
    this->year -= rhs.year;
    this->month -= rhs.month;
    this->day -= rhs.day;

    return *this;
}

inline date date::operator+(date lhs, const date& rhs)
{
  lhs += rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

Comment: Now make it a member-function, and the increment-operator.

Comment: `MonthLimit` also take an `int year`. I tried to implement the "increment smallest unit first" logic, but it got lost in the `if`s.

Comment: @Deduplicator: you mean add the code of the `increment_Date` to `class Date` as `Date::operator++`, and then rewrite the whole `for` loop?

Comment: @Chiffa: Yes. You might also consider adding a `normalize`-function, which takes a denormalized date (too many/too few monts/days maybe even wrong weekday).

Comment: On it. Now it's `Date::increment_Date`. But I'm now confused as to how should the loop look like.

Comment: @Baldrickk, thanks, but using `daycount` implies that we know it. In the problem I'm solving with this code, we don't, we only know the first and last date.

Comment: @Deduplicator: OK, got it about the loop, now all I have vector subscript out of range.

Comment: @Chiffa daycount was an example, that just provided `n` iterations.

Comment: @Chiffa I've just added in some code as I would do it for a class. The +/- functions could still do with some work, but most of the important stuff is there. - unfortunately I've run out of time today to finish this off.

Comment: at 240 lines, I think this is my longest answer so far.  I didn't quite intend it to be this long :P

Comment: @Exceptyon, I would if I weren't told not to. Also, thanks a lot, Baldrick.

Comment: @Chiffa No problem gave me something to do in my downtime at work. Feel free to accept if it was the most useful answer/solves your problem.